# Evitar acceso al log

Tags: php, mysql, html5, xampp

¿Qué puedo hacer si estoy haciendo una pagina web y quiero evitar que al estar iniciada la sesión permita acceder al log, pero me lanza un error?

[image: Este es el error que lanza]

### Código del log

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Frutillas</title>
</head>

<body>
   <?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION["sessionOK"]=="si"){
    header('location:exclusivoSesion.php');
}
?>
<form action="comparacion.php" method="post">

        Correo Electronico:
    <input type="email" name="email" required>

    <br>
    <br>

    Contraseña:
    <input type="password" name="password" required>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">

</form>

</body>
```

### Comparacin.php

```
<?php
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
$contrasena = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');

include ('acceso.php');

$sql = "select password from usuarios where email='".$email."';";
$sql2 = "select nombre from usuarios where email='".$email."';";

$resultado = $dp->query($sql);
$nombre = $dp->query($sql2);

$row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
$row2 = $nombre->fetch_assoc();

if ($row['password'] == $contrasena) 
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["sessionOK"]="si";
    $_SESSION["correo"]=$email;
    $_SESSION["nombre"]=$row2['nombre'];
    header ('location:exclusivoSesion.php');
} 
else {
    echo 'usuario o contraseña incorrecta';
    echo '<a href="login.php">Ir a login</a>';
}
mysql_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($dp);
```

?>

Comment: Hola amigo, por favor pon tu session_start() al principio de la web, y al principio de todo el codigo php

Comment: Disculpa, soy nuevo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes de validar primero que el índice de la sesión exista, `isset()` es para validar que la variable existe y `empty()` es para validar que no esté vacío. Tu problema es que estas tratando de invocar una sesión que quizá no existe.

[Revisa aquí la función isset()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php)

[Revisa aquí la función empty()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Frutillas</title>
</head>

<body>
   <?php
session_start();
if ( isset( $_SESSION["sessionOK"] ) && !empty( $_SESSION["sessionOK"] ) ){
    if( $_SESSION["sessionOK"] == 'si' ){
          header('location:exclusivoSesion.php');
    }
}
?>
<form action="comparacion.php" method="post">

        Correo Electronico:
    <input type="email" name="email" required>

    <br>
    <br>

    Contraseña:
    <input type="password" name="password" required>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">

</form>

</body>
```

Comment: Ya no me lanza ese error, muchas gracias, pero ahora el problema es que al iniciar sesión puedo dar clic en iniciar sesión y me deja volver a loguearme.

Comment: Hola, es facil en el login tienes que poner tambien un condicional que valide si existe la session, en caso de existir lo envias nuevamente a la web, y si no la tiene que permita hacer el login normalmente